# Modifying tuple created in lambda expression by reference

Tags: .net, reference, f#, tuples, pass-by-reference

I am trying to parse a very large log text file (100 000 lines +) after a test run on a certain software. In order to do this, I divide the file in windows of 1 000 lines and read incrementally each of these windows for each test in our test run. When I have finished reading those 1 000  lines, to make sure that I won't parse them for nothing again, I want to set a Boolean to true that means that I should just skip that window since I am sure I have finished parsing it.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
...
let windowedAMLogSeq = Seq.windowed 1000 fullAMLogSeq
                                |> Seq.map (fun (window:string[]) -> (window , false))
for category in sortedTrxFailedTests do
    for failedTest in category do
        ...
        match failedTest.StartTime with
        | Some x ->
            match failedTest.EndTime with
            | Some y ->
                let accessManagerLogLines = parseAccessManagerLogFile x y windowedAMLogSeq
                ...
```

with

```
let parseAccessManagerLogFile (testStartTime:DateTime) (testEndTime:DateTime) (windowedAMLogSeq:seq<string[] * bool>) =
    Seq.map (parseWindow testStartTime testEndTime) windowedAMLogSeq
```

and

```
let parseWindow testStartTime testEndTime (window:(string[] * bool)) =
    match (snd window) with
    | true ->
        [||]
    | false ->
        let lineArray = Array.map (fun (line:string) -> if (isBetweenStartAndEndTime testStartTime testEndTime line) then line else "") (fst window)
        let cleansedArray = Array.partition (fun (line:string) -> line <> "") lineArray
                                |> fst

        match cleansedArray.Length > 0 with
        | true ->
            ()
        | false ->
            window <- ((fst window), true)  // Problem here, not mutable or by ref
        cleansedArray
```

Obviously, this won't compile as `window` is not mutable or passed by reference. I have tried multiple combinations of using mutable and ref or byref keywords with no success. Being fairly new to F#, I am unsure of the correct syntax to use.

What would be the syntax to use in order to modify by reference the `window` value directly, or to be able to modify by reference the Boolean value in the `window` tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my question was to use the ref keyword like follows. Also, notice that you have to use the `.Value` property on the tuple now.

```
...
let windowedAMLogSeq = Seq.windowed 1000 fullAMLogSeq
                            |> Seq.map (fun (window:string[]) -> 
                                                let mutable tuple = ref (window , false)
                                                tuple
                                            )
for category in sortedTrxFailedTests do
    for failedTest in category do
        ...
        match failedTest.StartTime with
        | Some x ->
            match failedTest.EndTime with
            | Some y ->
                let accessManagerLogLines = parseAccessManagerLogFile x y windowedAMLogSeq
                ...
```

with

```
let parseAccessManagerLogFile (testStartTime:DateTime) (testEndTime:DateTime) (windowedAMLogSeq:seq<(string[] * bool) ref>) =
    Seq.map (parseWindow testStartTime testEndTime) windowedAMLogSeq
```

and

```
let parseWindow testStartTime testEndTime (window:(string[] * bool) ref) =
    match (snd window.Value) with
    | true ->
        [||]
    | false ->
        let lineArray = Array.map (fun (line:string) -> if (isBetweenStartAndEndTime testStartTime testEndTime line) then line else "") (fst window.Value)
        let cleansedArray = Array.partition (fun (line:string) -> line <> "") lineArray
                                |> fst

        match cleansedArray.Length > 0 with
        | true ->
            ()
        | false ->
            window.Value <- ((fst window.Value), true)

        cleansedArray
```

Comment: Note that it's more idiomatic to use the `(!)` operator instead of `.Value`: `match (snd !window) with ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the whole thing slightly cleaner by holding your window in a record type with a mutable field:

```
type LogWindow =
    {
        lines: string [] 
        mutable parsed: bool
    }
```

You create it like this:

```
let windowedAMLogSeq = Seq.windowed 1000 fullAMLogSeq
                       |> Seq.map (fun window -> { lines = window; parsed = false })
```

And then in your `parseWindow`:

```
window.parsed <- true
```

But your code looks really odd to me. Do you really want to create sliding windows of your log, rather than split it into chunks? Because what `Seq.windowed` creates are sliding windows.

Comment: I may be misinterpreting what `Seq.windowed` is doing as my code is not working (though with your fix or mine, it is compiling). Basically I do not want to store the whole log file (split or not) into an array or list as the file could potentially be bigger than the available RAM on the computer. This is why I was using sequences, as they are not stored in memory, but it is longer to compute each time. That is why I wanted to separate it in smaller windows and have a way to not have to parse the windows that I have already passed and know I won't come back to. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Then take a better look at what `Seq.windowed` is doing - it's probably creating ~99,000 windows out of 100,000 lines by moving one line at a time.

Comment: It is hard to look at what is happening in the debugger as I cannot see the sequences in it, it always times out. Is there a way to bypass the timeout in visual studio 2012?

Comment: Not sure what you're seeing. But usually it pays to turn seqs into arrays for debugging (not to mention using just a sample out of your gigantic log). Using F# interactive is also a good idea.

Comment: I think you should investigate how to read a file in chunks instead.